# How to resolve Unresolved Static Variable Error in MQL4/MQL5 for a struct array in an include file?

Tags: mql4, mql5

I have the following header/include file in mql4.

```
struct SStruct {
   int mInt;
};

class CMainClass {
public:
   static SStruct Arr[];
};

class COtherClass {

protected:
   void PrintArr();

};

void COtherClass::PrintArr(){
   for (int i=0; i<ArraySize(CMainClass::Arr); i++){
      PrintFormat("List[%i] = %i", i, CMainClass::Arr[i]);
   }
};

//SStruct CMainClass::Arr = {0};
```

and the following is the error I am getting:

```
unresolved static variable 'CMainClass::Arr'    CodingPractice.mqh
```

This attempt to initialize the array is producing even more errors:

```
SStruct CMainClass::Arr = {0};
```

Comment: Hi. I have this exact problem also. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: It has been quite a while and I don't remember much why it had to be static but now that I've seen this again, I am guessing the problem may have been due to the fact that the dynamic array was never resized (at least form this piece of code I have shared). I think I have moved on to just not using the static altogether and also by adding constructor and deconstructor inside the structure definition.